# How to add my document class to ShareTex and use it?

Tags: sharelatex

I want to write an article using `smjour.cls` class for [this journal](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1097-0118) in ShareLatex because we are three authors and we want to work together, however after uploading the class to ShareLatex and add `\documentclass{SMJOUR}` at the top of my file, I got the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `SMJOUR.cls' not found.
```

Any help would be appreciated! I think it is related to the file path but the class is uploaded into the root directory where the main.tex file is, as follow:

[image: my ShareLatex structure, document, and teh error]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Does it help if you rename the file from `SMJOUR.CLS` to `SMJOUR.cls`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer:

I create a new file with the ShareLatex IDE and then copy/paste all the content of my class to the new file and finally delete the old file and rename the new file to the name of the class and it works!

Hope to help others with the same problem.

Comment: That is not the usual way.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, I think you are right about the tex being case-sensitive, so you can add your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows users upload their files to a service like ShareLaTeX or share their files with, e.g., Linux users they are sometimes astonished by error messages about files, that cannot be found. This is, because not only TeX is case-sensitive but the filesystems of most operating systems in opposite to Windows are also case-sensitive. So if you upload a file `smjour.cls` to such a service, you have to use `\documentclass{smjour}` and not `\documentclass{SMJOUR}`. Note also, that LaTeX will not search for `smjour.CLS` or `SMJOUR.CLS`. The extension of a class file has to be `.cls` in lowers case.

Similar things often happen with graphics files, e.g., package `mwe` provides `example-image-a`. So `\includegraphics{Example-Image-A}` cannot be found on case-sensitive filesystems.