# Troubles compiling a given LaTeX-Template

Tags: bibliographies, texlive

So I am given a LaTeX-Template, which is said to be working with MikTex 2.9 und TeXLive 2016. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I have just downloaded TeXLive using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. As an editor, I am using Texstudio. I have tried to run the Template and the following error occurs:

```
Package biblatex Error: Style IEEE not found \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post some more of the log file.

Comment: Maybe a case problem. If the template was made by a Windows guy and he used `\usepackage[…,style=IEEE,…]{biblatex}` this should be replaced by `\usepackage[…,style=ieee,…]{biblatex}`. In this case tell the template maintainer, that [TeX is case-sensitiv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353987/9057).

Comment: thx, seems to be the problem! But as soon as I change IEEE to ieee, I get another error: ' Package keyval Error: giveninits undefined \blx@processoptions' . The problem occurs in biblatex1.sty - as I said, I have just reinstalled texlive, so shouldn't all my packages be up to date?

Comment: Without the template we can of course say nothing. But if there is someone who gave it to you and wants you to keep it private he should also provide a bit of support, I think. The `giveninits` message suggests your `biblatex` is outdated. If you installed the repository version of TeX live you may not get the newest updates. You only get full control over your TeX distribution if you use [vanilla TeX live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). However, normally there should be no version conflicts if you don't install packages manually.

Comment: That is, if you got both `biblatex` and `biblatex-ieee` from the Ubuntu repositories everything should be fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 ships a very, very outdated TeX live (namely TeX live 2013), you will have a hard time with packages that are more frequently updated such as `biblatex` and `pgfplots`. You should really consider getting a vanilla TeX live.

Comment: Would updating my version of ubuntu work as well?

Comment: Not sure. The repository versions of TeX live in Ubuntu are always a bit behind. It might just work, but upgrading your Ubuntu versions seems more hassle and potentially dangerous to me than installing vanilla TeX live.

Comment: You're using an unsupported version of Ubuntu in addition to an older TeX Live.  You need to move to more recent versions of software of possible.

Comment: What template is it? Why are you using it?

Comment: Any news here? As the question currently stands, the only thing we can say is that you are using a horribly outdated version of TeX live. We don't know more about the specifics of your template to be of any more help than that.

Comment: I think this is why it doesn't work. It is working now on a different computer, where I am using texlive 2016.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is related to outdated versions of the packages involved (TeX live 2013 is a long time ago in `biblatex` age) - OP confirms that the problem does not resurface with TeX live 2016.